# 80s Future post WWIII sci-fi fantasy adventure book id needed

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

The setting is a futuristic apocalyptic survival scenario caused by WWIII. The world is full of mutants created by rampant science and radioactive fall out there are several large human organizations that exist.

The largest and most technological advanced group with Superior military resources decides to put together an elite team of people from each of the other organizations to deal with the growing mutant societies that live in the wastes. it's headed by an elite warrior type whose favorite weapons are dual bowie knives.

Other main characters include

Bear - A mutant that is a hybrid between a bear and human created by a scientist. He is very stable and loyal, immensely strong and has retractable claws. his main role is protector of a women that was rescued from a previous mission.

A women who was rescued from a situation decides to join the group. shes a writer or reporter.

A street punk complete with leather jacket and switchblade. he turns into a pretty good fighter.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169717/post-apocalyptic-mens-adventure-novel (about the main series)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of the spin-off series "Blade", although he is also in the main series as well.

Endworld is a series of post-apocalyptic novels published by Leisure Books and written by David L. Robbins. The first book was published in 1986. As of 2014, there have been 29 novels written in the series. David Robbins also wrote a 13 novel spin-off to this series called Blade.

The series begins 100 years after World War III, a nuclear war between the United States and the Soviet Union. The series revolves around the predecessors of The Family, a survivalist group living in an isolated compound, called The Home, located in north-western Minnesota and their attempts to venture outside their secure home for the first time since the war. The United States itself was ravaged by nuclear, biological and chemical weapons and has become a dangerous place. Very little is known outside the country. In the novels, the Family's protectors, known as the Warriors, travel to cites and territories, usually dealing with some sort of threat to The Home such as dictators, mutants, etc. The leader of the Warriors, Blade, is the most prominent character.

Comment: Thank you i knew it was series but wasn't sure how big, the ones i read blade was charged to lead a group funded by a restored government.