# Post-apocalyptic Men's Adventure Novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a series of men's adventure novels.  The series is set in a post-apocalyptic future.  The good guys have gathered into a commune and have all taken different personas.  One is a western-style gunfighter who calls himself "Boone" (I think).  The other is a super-muscular fighter.  I can't remember exactly what the good guys did, but I know it was super manly.  I read a couple books in the series during the mid-90s.  Any ideas?

Comment: "I can't remember exactly what the good guys did, but I know it was super manly." Pee in the woods? Whinge about their colds? ;)

Comment: Manly in the Chuck-Norris-knocking-out-bad-guys-without-breaking-a-sweat way.

Comment: Well, definitely not [ this guy ](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boone_Helm), but that was a fun read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wonder if this could be the series by David L. Robbins. The main series is the [Endworld series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endworld), which runs to 29 books! He wrote a spin-off series called the Blade series (only 13 books in this one!).

Searching such a large series is somewhat problematic, and in any case I don't have all the books. However there is a gunfighter called Boone and the super muscular guy who is a mutant called Grizzly.

The books are set in a post apocalyptic America following a nuclear war with Russia. The group is called *The Family* and live in a settlement called *The Home* in Minnesota, which is kind of a commune I suppose.

Comment: I think that is it.  I can't figure out which one I read, but this sounds like it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess here.  William Johnstone's "Ashes" series.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Ashes_(Ashes_series)

[image]

Comment: I thought that might be it, but it doesn't look like it. No Boone.